# Sometimes Entity Framewok queries are very slow

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

We have the following piece of code:

```
        public async Task<bool> AreConsumerIdAndSecretExistAsync(AuthenticateConsumerRequest request)
    {
        return await _pplEntities.ApiConsumers.AnyAsync(ac =>
            ac.ConsumerId.Equals(request.ConsumerId) && ac.ConsumerSecret.Equals(request.ConsumerSecret));
    }
```

This queries a table containing only three rows of data.
For some reason, it sometimes takes a long time to execute the above method.
It's not the only place, where this issue occurs. It seems like in other places that run multiple SQL queries, it takes a long time to run the first queries, and other queries seem to be problem free. If I run the application locally, it's very fast, except for the first query.

Below is a picture of a New Relic trace showing how slow the application is. In other environments, we experience that the whole request takes upwards of 15 seconds; it's very confusing.

We're running on .NET 4.6.1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your screen shot is the number on the left the number of time its called or the time?... its the amount of times its called, not the time it takes right...
so its not slow your calling it alot...

avoid equals, this is a c# function and not sure if it has sql translations... where as '==' 100% I know does.

put index on the pr or fk or main lookup column

```
var res = _pplEntities.ApiConsumers
            .Where(ac => ac.ConsumerId  == request.ConsumerId 
                      && ac.ConsumerSecret == request.ConsumerSecret)
          .ToListAsync()

if(res.Any())
{
     //to stuff and things
}
```

Comment: Hey Seabizkit. The number on the left is the number of milliseconds that the operation took. I've added indices to the two columns that lookups are performed on. I'm sadly also noticing another external call to another REST API that at times takes a long time.

Comment: how far is your DB, physically located,  is ConsumerId indexed, and the record count is under 27 million then this should be faster than 1 sec. how many records are you returning, whats the size of the columns you are returning,... i assumed 1 row was being returned, but see its a list... so are you fetching..

Comment: ensure that the linq is converted to the correct SQL

Comment: just include more code aka how you consume this.... add the code.